# rspec "it" string

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is it possible for an rspec method to get the value of the parameter passed to  it() in the  local method?    For example, if I want:

```
describe Me do
  it "should figure this out"
    puts "I " + SPEC_NAME
  end
end
```

to print this:

```
I should figure this out
```

... what would I put for SPEC_NAME in the code sample?

Even better, how would a relatively new rubologist like me figure this out on his own?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `description` method should do what you want. e.g.

```
describe Me do
  it "should figure this out" do
    puts "I " + description # or "I #{description}" using string interpolation
  end
end
```

In terms of how to figure this out, I found it by looking in the [RDocs for RSpec](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.3.0/), starting by looking at the source of the [it](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.3.0/classes/Spec/Example/ExampleGroupMethods.html#M000258) method to see how it works. You will then find that RSpec refers to the "it" string as the "description" so you can look for available methods that include description in their name.

I know it's not much use to you right now, but as you learn more Ruby you'll find it easier to read the code in libraries like RSpec and will develop an instinct for how they are likely to be implemented, which will help you look in the right places for things.

Comment: I tried with RSpec 2.8.0, but it didn't work straight away. What object was this running on? I found: RSpec::ExampleGroup::Nested_2 (I guess it's ExampleGroup for you) The solution for me is:  example.description

Comment: +1 for including instructions on how to figure things like this out from the source/docs.

Answer (score 1):

With more recent versions of RSpec (I'm using 2.14), you can refer to it as `example.description`.

```
it "prints itself" do
  puts "My description string is '#{example.description}'."
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question exactly, but if you're trying to print out each test as it runs, put this in your `spec.opts` file:
`--format specdoc`

Here's an example of what my tests look like when I run them:

```
A new release when parsing the artist containing a full join word
- should remove it
- should not remove it when it is inter-word

A new release when parsing the artist containing an abbreviated joining word
- should remove it when there is a period after it
- should remove it when when there is not a period after it
- should not remove it when it is inter-word with a period after it
- should not remove it when it is inter-word without a period after it

A new release when parsing the artist
- should be invalid if the year is not current
- should be valid if it is the current year
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but great tip nonetheless!